# Email Templates from Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

i will be creating a responsive email newsletter, and i notice that there is framework for this purpose called Zurb Foundation Email, but since im more used to work in bootstrap, isnt it available anything from Bootstrap to create newslleter responsive emails.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately bootstrap doesn't provide any official email templates.

But you can go with who are expert in this field creating newsletters : MailChimp

Link 1 : https://github.com/mailchimp/email-blueprints 
Link 2 : http://templates.mailchimp.com/

You'll able to understand concept even better with Link 2.